# making the height the same of all items in owl Carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am making an Owl Carousel. So I did this

```
 <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Books)
        {
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="~/@item.Src" alt="Owl Image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @item.Name
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

and this is CSS

```
  <style>
        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .item {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        .card{
            padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
        }
    </style>
```

how can I make the yellow section(.item) of all items the same height?

Comment: You can just use `height: 50px !important;`, right?

Comment: @ArchitGargi: is it ok for being responsive? setting fixed height?

Comment: Yes it is if you put it as percentage and not pixels.

Comment: @ArchitGargi: this is the exact problem, according to my code, what percentage should I set to item class? if i set heightL100% to item class, that doesn't make the items the same height

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS style for `.owl-stage`:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  display:flex !important 
/*!important not required but maybe need if there some others css rules for .owl-stage display */
}
```

Dont use `align-items` property and `.owl-item` get height 100% from the highest item from this carousel items.